# Appropriate gauge-invariant counterterms for Maxwell field in $AdS_5$

Tags: electromagnetism, renormalization, ads-cft

I am starting with the bulk Maxwell field in $AdS_5$, and want to calculate the on-shell action. My metric is

$$ds^2 = \dfrac{dz^2 - dt^2 + \vec{dx^2}}{z^2}$$

from which I calculate the on-shell action. Now I have chosen the following gauge conditions for the Maxwell field

$$A_z = 0$$
and fixed the residual gauge symmetry to

$$\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu} =0$$

where $\mu$ goes over only the spacetime indices. My regularized onshell action comes out to be

$$ S_{reg} = \dfrac{-1}{2} \int d^4x \Big[    \dfrac{A_{\mu}}{z^4} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(g^{\mu \nu} A_{\nu})\Big]_{z=\epsilon}$$

When I put the allowed solution into the action, I get something the divergent part part of the action I am getting is something of the form, where $q^2 = \vec{k}^2 - \omega^2$, and $k$ is the four-momentum.

$$ S_{reg} = \dfrac{-1}{2} \int d^4k {} \xi_{\mu} \xi_{\nu} \eta^{\mu \nu} \Big[ \dfrac{2\epsilon^{-3}}{q^2} + (-1 + 3 \gamma_E + 3 log [\dfrac{-q^2}{2}])\epsilon^{-1} + \dfrac{3log\epsilon}{\epsilon} + O(\epsilon^1)\Big]$$

What are the appropriate counterterms that I should put to absorb these divergences?  Will putting something like the one below work, where $\mu$ goes over only the spaceime indices?
$$S_{ct} = \dfrac{-\delta_{ct}}{4} \int d^4x  F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$

Comment: Can you calculate the counter-term contribution to the action and write it down?

Comment: also the integral is in the momentum space, right?

Comment: the integral is fixed, let me write the counterterm down explicitly